# ARM on CentOS 7

Tags: nyx

I'm currently hosting a tor exit relay running on CentOS 7 64-bit and i heard about arm and i've been trying to get it to work on Centos and nothing is working. I tried sudo "yum install tor-arm" and it says that there isn't a package available. I searched everywhere on google and the official Arm page and nothing is working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Did you download from here : https://www.atagar.com/arm/download.php ?
Can you elaborate on what goes wrong? we need more details.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google resulted in the following page, which details both how to set up a relay on CentOS, *and* how to install ARM:

https://www.pixeljumble.com/how-to-setup-a-tor-relay-on-centos/

The pertinent parts are:

1. Download ARM from https://www.atagar.com/arm/download.php
2. Install the package: `rpm -ivh arm-replace-with-version-downloaded.rpm`
3. Restart Tor: `service tor restart`
4. Run ARM: `arm`

The documentation for ARM can be found in its README. From the ARM [homepage](https://www.atagar.com/arm/) you can follow the links to the associated [Git repository](https://gitweb.torproject.org/nyx.git/log/?h=release), under which ARM is actually referred to as **nyx**. The README can be found [here](https://gitweb.torproject.org/nyx.git/tree/README?h=release).

Answer (score 0):

Posting despite the fact this is an old topic, given it is a popular hit when searching for this.

Posted at https://www.reddit.com/r/TOR/comments/d8td66/quickdirty_installation_guide_for_installing_nyx/ as well.

**TL;DR**: pip3.x is probably the easiest way for CentOS/RHEL7.

Prerequisites:
* A functioning tor node
* `ControlPort 9051` and `CookieAuthentication 1` in your `torrc` file.

Step 1: Install Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) repository configuration

`sudo yum -y install epel-release`

Step 2: Install python34-setuptools

`sudo yum -y install python34-setuptools`

Step 3: Install pip

`sudo easy_install-3.4 pip`

Step 4: Install nyx itself

`sudo pip3.7 install nyx`

Step 5: Enjoy `nyx`!

`nyx`

N.B.: `nyx` will run as root but there is no benefit to doing so and you probably should practice not running things as root for the lols.